# Android setRepeating() and setInexactRepeating() do not fire

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I did not find a solution for this absurd problem. setRepeating() and setInexactRepeating() do not fire at all. I tried both this methods. The following is my code:

```
Intent intentService = new Intent(context, ServiceReceiver.class);
intentService.putExtra("checkStrikeAndNews", true);
PendingIntent pendingIntentSN = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,   0,intentService, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

//scheduling checkNews
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pendingIntentSN);
```

I also tried with setInexactRepeating() and it does not work. I also used ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP and SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), same behaviour.

The broadcast receiver ServiceReceiver.class works perfectly it receives other intent and alarm intent (AlarmManager set() and setExact()) without problems. I tested the code on ICS, JellyBean and Marshmallow.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. I think you have to use `PendingIntent.getService()` instead of `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`
2. Be sure your service is declared in your `Manifest.xml`
3. It's better to use `setInexactRepeating()` for battery life

**App.class** where I setup the alarm

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static final int INTERVAL = 1000 * 60;
    private static final int DELAY = 5000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        setupAlarm();
    }

    private void setupAlarm() {
        PendingIntent myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, MyService.newIntent(this), 0);
        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, DELAY, INTERVAL, myPendingIntent);
    }
}
```

**MyService.class** where I manage the intent received

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = MyService.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String EXTRA_CHECK = "checkStrikeAndNews";

    /**
     * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
     */
    public MyService() {
        super("MyService");
    }

    public static Intent newIntent(Context context) {
        return new Intent(context, MyService.class) //
                .putExtra(EXTRA_CHECK, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_CHECK, false)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "I just received an intent");
        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml** Where I declared my service

```
<manifest
    package="com.darzul.test"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".App"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".service.MyService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**EDIT 01/02/2015**

Here is the code with a `BroadcastReceiver`

**App.class**

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static final int INTERVAL = 1000 * 60;
    private static final int DELAY = 5000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        setupAlarm();
    }

    private void setupAlarm() {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, DELAY, INTERVAL, myPendingIntent);
    }
}
```

**WARNING:** If you're testing on a device with a SDK equal or greater than 5.1, your interval alarm cannot be less than 1 minute.

> Value will be forced up to 60000 as of Android 5.1; don't rely on this to be exact
>   Frequent alarms are bad for battery life. As of API 22, the AlarmManager will override near-future and high-frequency alarm requests, delaying the alarm at least 5 seconds into the future and ensuring that the repeat interval is at least 60 seconds.  If you really need to do work sooner than 5 seconds, post a delayed message or runnable to a Handler.

**MyReceiver.class**

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "MyReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive");
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<manifest
    package="com.darzul.test"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".App"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:exported="false"
            android:name=".receiver.MyReceiver" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! :) it works! :) Why with a broadcast receiver does not work ?

Comment: Glad it's working :)

- getBroadcast() is for Receivers
- getService() if for Services

Comment: Okay, but my  ServiceReceiver, is a BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Mmmm ok, I'll edit the answer soon to add a Receiver between Alarm and Service :)

Comment: @DarzuL any answer for the Receiver between Alarm and Service?

Comment: @user2179059 Sorry for the (big) delay. Here is the update :)